# Which version of Eclipse should I be downloading?

Tags: eclipse, ide

I just want to develop some Java and Python applications on Windows XP. Which version should I be using:

- Eclipse IDE for Java Developers, 99MB
- Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers, 206 MB
- Eclipse Classic 3.6.1, 170 MB

Comment: it doesn't actually matter that much - if you need the other features/plugins you can always add them later. I normally start with IDE for Java Developers myself as it is relatively lightweight, then add the other stuff as I need it.

Comment: They now have a comparison chart and one can select a few to narrow the field: [Compare Eclipse Packages](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/compare.php).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Eclipse IDE for Java Developers - simply made for Java developers. If you develop standalone or similar applications, this is your choice

Eclipse Classic - also has modules to develop Java applications, but also provides different other plugins (extra plugins, which may be unrelated to Java)

Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers - if you are going to develop dynamic web applications with help of Java, this is what you need.

Make your choice, then in Eclipse go to "Help/Eclipse Marketplace...", type there "python" and on the top you will see PyDev (already mentioned by @cschol), click install :) Using Marketplace you can find other plugins you need for work (just tell it because new Eclipse MArketplace seems to be less known feature of Eclipse Helios platform)

Answer (score 3):

The Eclipse Classic version comes with Java support out-of-the-box. The version for Java Developers might just have a couple of packages more specifically tailored to a Java development workflow.

Find a comparison chart of the different versions [here](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/moreinfo/compare.php).

In any version you can install other packages using the built-in Eclipse installation/update system.

For developing Python applications with Eclipse you will definitely want to install [PyDev](http://pydev.org/).